# I'm trying to write an asynchronous pathfinding function using async await in javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm testing if it works and a function that runs a while loop will block the code even if it is in an asynchronous function that I am awaiting. How do do something like pathfinding without freezing my webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing *work* keeps the main JS event loop busy.

You can't get around that by using promises or the `async` and `await` tools. They are tools to *manage* asynchronous code, they don't make code asynchronous.

A couple of strategies you could employ are:

- Moving the work off the main event loop and into a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).
- Doing the work in chunks with chunk  triggering the processing of chunk +1 using `setTimeout` to introduce a delay during which the main event loop can pick up other work that is waiting for it.